# /wp-admin/admin.php? give 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wp-admin

I have a problem when I try to access the menu added by plugins in the wordpress Left sidebar.

For example when I click on WP Socializer it call this url :

```
 http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wp_socializer&tab=buttons
```

and return 404 error '[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKDoX.png)'

But when I change manually the URL and remove admin.php it works.

I cannot understand the problem

Can someone help me please ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did this issue occurs after you installed any plugin or make some changes in you .htaccess?

Comment: it seems the problem is related to the link added in menu by the plugin, not in .htaccess or other

Comment: the admin.php should not be there..

Comment: when I click on one of the links it give 404 not found Screenshot : https://i.imgur.com/Toi3j18.png

Result : https://i.imgur.com/i0urg52.png